# Check if a file exists in Yii

Tags: php, yii, file-exists

I am creating a bunch of modules that all extend a base module. However, some actions need to override the base view. In that case, I'd like to check if the new module has a view in its structure. If it does, use that view, and otherwise use the base one. Now, my question:

**Is there a way to check if a file exists in Yii, using the typical alias structure `application.views.user.basic_view` without using or importing it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use Controller or CWidget method `getViewFile`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getViewFile-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#getViewFile-detail

Answer (score 7):

Untested, but what's about resolving the alias to a path and then check this...

```
 echo is_file(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.user.basic_view'))?'yes':'no';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though it might work, I already tested @Sergey's answer and it worked. However, +1 for noticing the `getPathOfAlias` `false` return in case the file doesn't exist.